# Need to get a service to talk back to the activity

Tags: android, android-service

I need to create an activity that starts a service that monitors the users position and when within a certain zone allow the calling Activity to update its view informing the user.

Since there are a few different ways to work with services I am a little confused to which of these is the correct one for my situation.

**Use the `startService()` and `stopService()` methods**:  From what I understand I can't directly talk back to the starting activity.  In the google docs there is an [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) showing how to pass a BroadcastReceiver to the service via a PendingIntent and call it, but  I don't think that allow for me to update the running activity's view...or will it?

**Bound Service**: From the docs it seems that this will allow for 2-way communication between the service and activity, but it was also mentioned that bound services don't run in the background [indefinitely](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html).  Now I don't need, or even want, the service to run indefinitely, but in the worst case scenario I could need it to run in the bg for at least an hour or two without being killed.

**Third (probably not so great) option**: Run the location service in a thread in the activity, which will make real-time view updates easy, then in the onPause event, stop the location service in the activity and hand it off to a service via `startService()` and use the notification service to alert the user when a defined zone has been entered.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

1. [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) says

   > if you want the service to send a result back, then the client that starts the service can create a PendingIntent for a broadcast (with getBroadcast()) and deliver it to the service in the Intent that starts the service. The service can then use the broadcast to deliver a result.
2. and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) says

   > A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to try a [Bound Service using a Messenger](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Messenger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, option (2) is probably what you want. You can override `onStartCommand` to return `START_STICKY` and the Service will continue to run after the Activity finishes.

When you `bindService` you can get the actual Service instance back and then just invoke your custom methods on that as a way of communicating. Alternatively you could use one of the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample.)

Comment: That is a good example, but it doesn't make clear whether I can call methods in the activity from the service.  Is this doable, or does it only work in the reverse direction?

Comment: It is doable: you call a method on the Service and pass in the Activity instance. You can then call any methods on the Activity (as long as they are not private and are suitably visible to the Service). You do have to be very careful to watch for situations where the Activity is destroyed and is no longer valid.

Comment: Using a similar style to the LocalServiceSample and passing in a reference to the activity worked perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: This project implement this service (BothService) and shows that how can a Service run indefinitely and also allow binding with multiple activities. (https://github.com/shanrais/BothService)

Answer (score 8):

You can have a Service which is both bound and is started via `startService()`. Using the `ServiceConnection` you can have two way communication and using `startService()/stopService()` you can control it's lifetime.

The lifecycle image from the android site really explains it well:
[image: Lifecycle]

By binding and starting the service you will get a service which can run indefinitely. The service will only stop if both of the following conditions are true:

1. There are no clients bound to it.
2. stopService() was called.

It requires a bit more maintenance but I found this to be the most reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

Binding with service will be the best way to do this.

Put this code in your activity onCreate and define your service with implementing onBind method returning the binder object. Define your IBinder properly in your service.

This will ensure service running all the time in the background. And every time your activity starts it will bind with the service. In the onDestroy() method of your activity unbind the service. Otherwise it will throw ServiceLeakedException.

```
   YourService service;   

   ServiceConnection  serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binderService) {
          service = ((YourService.ServiceBinder)binderService).getService();
      }

      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

      }
   };

    // ... and bind.
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

On the basis of any calculation your service can launch your activity itself. As it get launched it will bind with the service. Then further communication can occur.

Hope it helps :)